# How can I show an old submission value in form field?

Tags: php, database, forms, default-value, submission

I created a form by RSForm. I have two textbox in it.
First textbox name is km1 (new_km) and second textbox name is km2 (old_km).
In the first time, user will fill km1 field (new_km) by her car kilometer number.
When the user recourse again and fill the form, km2 (old_km) must shown value that user entered it in previous recourse.
Please guide me?
Best regards.

Right, I know, my English is very bad. sorry.

Like this image: http://persianupload.com/kleeja/do.php?imgf=141839395854871.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I personally use session for that...

**Your html:**

```
<?php
 session_start();
 if(!isset($_SESSION['something'])) $_SESSION['something'] = '';
?>
<input type="text" name="something" value="<?php $_SESSION['something']?>"/>
```

**Your receiver php:**

```
<php
 session_start();
 if($_POST['something']) $_SESSION['something'] = $_POST['something'];
?>
```